# Association rules with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, orange

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[980,169,104,74], columns=['Count'], index=['X,Y,Z', 'X,Z','X','Y,Z'])

           Count
X, Y, Z      980
X,Z          169
X            104
Y,Z           74
```

I want to be able to extract association rules from this. I've seen that the **Apriori algorithm** is the reference. And also found the *Orange library* for data mining is well-known in this field.

But the problem is, in order to use the [AssociationRulesInducer](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.associate.html) I need to create first a file containing all the transactions. Since my dataset is really huge (20 columns and 5 million rows) it will be too expensive to write all this data in a file and read it again with Orange.

Do you have any idea how can I take advantage of my current dataframe structure in order to find association rules ?

Comment: Just add the dataframe code to be able to test, sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The new [Orange3-Associate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange3-Associate) add-on for [Orange data mining suite](http://orange.biolab.si) seems to include widgets and [code that mines frequent itemsets](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-associate/blob/1d17c1bcfd0108fd087fb4e0d90fab923723c8a2/orangecontrib/associate/fpgrowth.py#L221) (and from them [association rules](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-associate/blob/1d17c1bcfd0108fd087fb4e0d90fab923723c8a2/orangecontrib/associate/fpgrowth.py#L267)) even from sparse arrays or lists of lists, which may work for you.

With 5M rows, it'd be quite awesome if it did. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but to anyone running into this question when trying to use pandas dataframes for association rules and frequent itemsets (e.g. Apriori):

Have a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-apriori-algorithm-in-python/) blog entry explaining how to do that using library `mlxtend`.

My only recommendation regarding this great blog entry is that if you are dealing with large datasets, you may run into OOM errors for hot-encoded dataframes. I recommend using SparseDtypes then: `df = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype(int, fill_value=0))`